# click on button parentElement execute 2 times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, parent

[image][image]

I am facing problem in javascript. I want to do if user click on `send` button then the code will execute one `time` and only show first name value only one time

```js
  $(document).on("click", "#send_button", function (e){   
  //name shows 2 times
   console.log(this.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[3].innerHTML);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
   <button id="send_button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>
</td>
```

JSON data:

```
{name: "test", body: "test"}
{name: "test2", body: "test2"}
```

Code Output:

```
test //execute name 2 times
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please update your snippet to a [mcve]

Comment: You have jQuery, use it: `$(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(3).text()`

Comment: output attached [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan)

Comment: Please show CODE, not PICTURES of code

Comment: Also make sure there are no event handlers on the row

Comment: You shouldn't add the same id #send_button to different html elements. You might want to use class instead of id

Comment: now check the code [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan)

Comment: can check my code  what mistake i am doing? [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12844058/peprumo)

Comment: this is will be repeated for each list-row, ids should be unique in all the html

Comment: i use `class` but it not working [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12844058/peprumo)

Answer (score 0):

Change your button to:

```
<button class="send-button btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>
```

so that `send-button` is a class.

And then your javascript should be:

```
$(document).on("click", ".send_button", function (e) {   
    console.log($(this).closest("tr").find("td.name").text());
});
```

Comment: thanks i try but not working shows empty [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12844058/peprumo)

Comment: If you want to get the name it seems it should be `.find("td").eq(1)` as it's the second td and it starts from 0. Or, even better, `.find("td.name")` to get the one with name class. If this doesn't work post your html as text so we can try to reproduce it

Comment: `.find("td.name")` yes it working but again it shows name 2 times on console [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12844058/peprumo)